# Python Flask and Psycopg -- Query string request.get in WHERE

Tags: python, flask, psycopg

What is the correct way to pass query string variables in flask to psycopg as a parameter in a WHERE clause?

Specifically, if the variable is not set, I do not want the variable added to the WHERE clause:

```
 id = int(request.args.get('id'))
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = %s;", id)
```

If id is None, I want the SQL with no WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM data
```

Is the only way to do this is with an if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just issue a different query if no (valid) `id` query parameter was provided:

```
id = request.args.get('id', type=int)
if id is not None:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = %s", (id,))
else:
    # No (valid) id given, give everything
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
```

Note that I used the `type` keyword argument for the [`MultiDict.get()` method](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get); the method returns a default value (`None` unless specified otherwise via the `default` argument) if the key is missing or can't be converted to an integer.